# R Shiny deployment not finding source of package

Tags: r, shiny, package, shinyapps

I have an R Shiny app that worked well until 2 weeks ago when it stopped deploying correctly on shinyapps.io. I downloaded the new version of R (4.1.3) and re-downloaded all of the packages as well, but  and now when I deploy the app, it takes a long time where the packages are building, with messages like this:

`/mnt`
`[2022-03-29T11:44:08.002002150+0000] Building R package: boot (1.3-28)`
`/mnt/packages/build /mnt`
`Warning: unknown option ‘--vanilla’`

`installing to library ‘/opt/R/4.1.3/lib/R/library’`

`installing` *`source`* `package ‘boot’ ...`
`** package ‘boot’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked`
`** using staged installation`
`** R`
`** data`
`*** moving datasets to lazyload DB`
`** inst`
`** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading`
`** help`
`*** installing help indices`
`** building package indices`
`** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location`
`** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location`
`** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path`

`creating tarball`
`packaged installation of ‘boot’ as ‘boot_1.3-28_R_x86_64-pc-linux-gnu.tar.gz’`

`DONE (boot)`

**However, then I get an error like: "Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 1125925494 failed: Error building image: Error fetching corrplot (0.92) source. Error downloading package source:
Execution halted"

I have checked to make sure that the packages are in the folder with the others, and they are, so I'm not sure what the issue is. I've also tried re-downloading the packages.

Does anybody have any advice? I am thinking I may need to delete and re-download all of the packages - but I'm not entirely sure how to cleanly do that.

THank you!

I have tried updating all packages, re-installing packages that seem to have issues, and I switched to using 'renv' to manage the packages. I also tried copying and pasting my app.R code into another app and publishing that, but it did the same thing. Another app that I have on the same shinyapps.io server worked as expected, however, and when deploying this app, the long messages that the packages are being built do not appear.